# JQuery, $(this) not correct in fadeIn, fadeOut callback function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to fadeOut() an image on the page and remove it from the DOM after the animation is finished. Sounds easy enough?

Example code (image has the id "img1"):

```
   $("#img1").fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove() });
```

This does does not work. When I inspect the page with Firebug the image is still there. It is just hidden.

Second example which should kind of flash the image:

```
   $("#img1").fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).fadeIn() });
```

Strange.

---

Thanks for the example pages which work great and as expected.

The problem must be something else and only occurs in my project environment.

Side note: when I do a simple console.log($(this)) in my callback function the result is the window object itself?!

When I find out what side effects create the problem I'll update this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of examples work as expected for me, as demonstrated [here](http://jsbin.com/exacu) (apologies for the bad image, it was the first thing I found!). Image 1 fades out  and then is removed from the DOM, Image2 fades out then back in, in the position of where Image1 was originally positioned.

Have I understood you correctly?

P.S. You can edit the example [here](http://jsbin.com/exacu/edit)

Answer (score 3):

> Query supports chaining, which means
>   you can obtain the same thing with the
>   following commands:
>
> $('#img1').fadeOut('slow').remove();
>   $('#img1').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
>
> It looks nicer, and it'll work =)

```
$('#img1').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

will work because jQuery will queue effects, but when you call

```
$('#img1').fadeOut('slow').remove();
```

framework will run fadeOut in background and acts remove() before object even begin to fade out

Comment: +1 for explaining why effect chaining  and .remove() act differently

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me.  The HTML Inspector in Firebug 1.2.1 clearly shows the element being removed.  Perhaps you're not using the latest JQuery?

My test code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("p").click(function () {
      $("p").fadeOut("slow", function()
      {
         $(this).remove();
      });
    });

  });
  </script>
  <style>
  p { font-size:150%; cursor:pointer; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    If you click on this paragraph
    you'll see it just fade away.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery supports chaining, which means you can obtain the same thing with the following commands:

```
$('#img1').fadeOut('slow').remove();
$('#img1').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

It looks nicer, and it'll work =)

Comment: We I tried here last time it didn't work. The image was removed instantly, so I had to use the callback function, exactly like OP did.

Comment: when you do the chaining, it is not guaranteed to happen one after the other, in fact it rarely does happen one after the other, this is why using the callback function ensures that the remove and fadeIn occurs after the fadeOut has completed